# IV and Mediator have reciprocal relation

Tags: mediation

I am trying to create a mediation model for:

X1=employee capability; 
X2 (Mediator)=Company capability; 
Y= employee earnings

Although, I am not sure if I can still say that this will be a mediation model when I believe and support that X1 and X2 have reciprocal relation. Where, employee capability (X1) explains the company capability (X2) and vice-versa then both affect employee earnings(Y).

First, is this considered a usual mediation model?

Second, whatever model it will be, how do I proceed with the analysis/process?

Thanks.